# Magento 2: How to disable cart price rule for free shipping after coupon code is used

Tags: magento2, magento-2.3

I am struggling on a case where I have set a cart price rule that applies free shipping to all carts where the amount is higher than 140 USD - works with no problem at all.

The problem is when a customer applies discount code and here is an example:

- Total cart value 148 USD, customer now have a free shipping
- Customer applies 10% discount coupon and the total price goes down to 133.20 USD

Current behaviour: Even after the discount the customer still gets free shipping.

Expected behaviour: Add shipping costs if the price goes under 140 USD to carts where a coupon code has been applied.

Answer (score 0):

The cart price Rule in Magento 2 is applied to the subtotal in your case, not to the grand total.

See the scenario:

Subtotal: 140 USD
Discount: 10%
Grand Total: 132.20
Shipping: 0

So, to apply the cart price rule, the customer will still get Free Shipping as the subtotal is: 140 USD.

To fix this please check the below link:
https://aureatelabs.com/blog/add-grand-total-in-the-shopping-cart-rule-condition/

You need to do it with Custom Code.
That's it